# Client can not connect again with the server after the first communication TCP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Why client can't connect again with the server?When should I close the socket?

First client sent the message and received message from the server. Everything was Ok. Then client read something from file and attended to send to the server. I don't know where the problem stands. Is the problem to the client or to the server? Or I close the wrong socket?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Connection to Server
    String serverHostname = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 10007;

    System.out.println("Attemping to connect to host " + serverHostname
            + " on port " + port);

    Socket echoSocket = null;


    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, port);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: "
                + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Declare the DataOutput and the DataInput
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            echoSocket.getInputStream()));

    String msgIn, msgOut;

    msgOut = "TEST";

    out.println(msgOut);

    msgIn = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("RETURN: " + msgIn);
    msgOut = "l";
    out.println(msgOut);
    msgIn = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("RETURN: " + msgIn);
    // Close all connections
    out.close();
    in.close();
    echoSocket.close();
}
```

}

```
     import java.net.*;
     import java.io.*;

     public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10007);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10007.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");

    try {
        // The socket accepted by the client
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Accept connection from "
                + clientSocket.getLocalAddress().toString() + ":"
                + clientSocket.getPort());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Connection successful");
    System.out.println("Waiting for input.....");

    // Get input and output streams associated with the socket.

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    String msgIn, msgOut;

    msgIn = in.readLine();

    System.out.println("Server IN: " + msgIn);

    msgOut = msgIn + " OK ";

    out.println(msgOut);

    out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}
```

}

```
         Attemping to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 10007
       RETURN: TEST OK 
     Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software  caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at Client.main(Client.java:45)
```

Comment: Can you add to your question a description of the protocol the client and server are using (or are supposed to be using) to communicate with each other? Otherwise, it's literally impossible to determine if the client and/or server implement the correct protocol which is what is needed for the code to work. Also, why does the "server" keep closing the listening socket?

Comment: Tcp protocol. It is my first day that I work with computer network

Comment: No, I don't mean the network protocol, I mean the application protocol. The one the client and server use to communicate with each other. (Application protocols are things like HTTP, FTP, SMTP, and so on that define how the information is encoded, where it begins and ends, how the connection is shut down, and so on.) If you think that you can use TCP without precisely defining the bytes to be exchange and how the messages are marked, your code will *never* work except by accident.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to find out which I'm using

Comment: You wrote the code and you don't know how it's supposed to work? Then you really are just hoping it will work by accident.

Comment: I don't know what to tell. When I wanted to send another message, then it didn't work.

Comment: First communication was Ok

Comment: Because there is no such thing as a "message" in this context. The only way there could be a message is if the application protocol defined a "message" in some precise way and you had written code to send and receive a "message" as defined in that protocol. But you have not done that. So there is no such thing as a "message".

Answer (score 0):

When you write program that use TCP to communicate, they have to communicate using some application level protocol. If one side is going to send a message to the other, the protocol has to specify how the end of the message is marked and what bytes the message will contain and what they mean.

Examples of such protocols are SMTP (used to send email), HTTP (used to send web pages), and FTP (used to send files). Each of these has a written document that explains what bytes are exchanged, what they mean, and how senders and receivers are expected to encode and parse them.

Without such a specification, it is impossible to figure out whether your server and client do what they're supposed to do because the concept of "what they're supposed to do" has not yet been formed.

Look at existing protocol specifications and write one for the protocol your server and client are using. Then you can check if the server and client comply with the protocol to debug them.

This will be difficult the first time you do it, but after a few times it will become easier. It is vital to writing reliable network software. You can only succeed by luck without a specified protocol.

TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a message protocol. Your applications are trying to send and receive messages, so you need an application-level message protocol to define how they'll do that. Then you need to write code to send and receive "messages", as defined by the application-level protocol. Without it, you are attempting the impossible -- trying to send messages with no code that has any idea what a "message" actually is.

For example, your protocol could define a "message" as "a group of bytes not containing any newlines or zero bytes terminated by a newline". Then you could write code to send a "message" by putting a newline on the end and code to receive a "message" by retrieving chunks of bytes and scanning them for newlines. But you've not done that.

Comment: @Boris How do you know it "worked" the first time without some protocol that specifies what it means for it to "work"? You do not know what it's suppose to do! Why do you consider whatever it happened to do working? (Likely it worked literally by accident. Optimizations in TCP often cause bytes to happen to stick together. But such code is *very* fragile and *often* fails at the worst possible time and almost always in unusual environments.)

Comment: Because the first time client "message" returned back. I want the same thing to happen again

Comment: I really can't say for sure because the specification is only in your head and I have no access to your head. Perhaps you really did mean for messages to be lines? Perhaps in your head is a reasonable specification that both the server and client comply with.